# To insert value of all selected Check Boxes in database in php

Tags: php

I have a form and have some fields in it. Check box is also fields for hobbies and when i submit that form then values are inserted in database and it redirect to another form and show the values from database in table format.But I have a problem when showing the result in table manner is it is not showing the values of all selected check boxes it just show the last selected check box's value. 
And one more thing can i show password in *** form or hash form not just simple text form when showing in table format

```
<head>
<title>Sunil1</title>
</head>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Unable to create to connection");
mysql_select_db("sunil") or die(mysql_error());
$Name1=$_POST["t1"];
$Name2=$_POST["t2"];
$Sex=$_POST["sex"];
$Country=$_POST["Country"];
$Hobby=$_POST["check"];
$Email=$_POST["t3"];
$Pass=$_POST["p1"];
$Repass=$_POST["p2"];
$sql="INSERT INTO registration (First_Name,Last_Name,Sex,Country,Hobbies,Email,Password,Repassword) VALUES('$Name1','$Name2','$Sex','$Country','$Hobby','$Email','$Pass','$Repass')";
mysql_query($sql);
print"Data Submitted Successfully";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration");
print "<table border=1>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>".$row['First_Name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Last_Name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Sex']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Country']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Hobbies']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Password']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Repassword']."</td>";
        print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: @Sunil-Bhai Please paste your code as well.

Comment: *"And one more thing can i show password in * form or hash form not just simple text form when showing in table format"* - Passwords saved as simple text is not a good idea. You might find that out "the hard way" later on. Good luck with that.

Comment: I had paste it tell me where to use md5() here

Comment: What about my first question of inserting check boxes values i haven't get any result yet

Comment: Since you already accepted the answer below, you'll need to post a new question. And do take my suggestions seriously, and also use `MySQLi_` with prepared statements or use PDO instead of `MySQL_`. Your site stands at eventually getting hacked; it's just a question of time. [**Read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for password please write like this

```
print "<td>".md5($row['Password'])."</td>"; or print "<td>".md5('$row['Password']')."</td>";
```

this will display your password in hash.

Comment: You shouldn't be promoting/encouraging `md5` password storage. You should be addressing the issue with a better method.